# Converting SAS EG Data Step to Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, sas

I'm trying to convert the following Data Step from SAS EG to SPARK SQL

```
data work.Test;
set WORK.PROGRAM3;
by Year Month Day;
if first.Month then HLProfit=0;
HLProfit+HighLevelProfit;
if first.Month then UnearnedRev=0;
UnearnedRev + UnearnedRevenue_Total;
run;
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the **data** function using Spark SQL.

> ParseException:
> mismatched input 'data' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD'}

Appreciate if any of you can give some direction on this as I am new to this.

The expected output will be first day of the month will have HLProfit=0 and UnearnedRev=0, and then this will gradually add up as the no of days increases.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the output I want using the code below:

```
PROGRAM3 = spark.sql(""" SELECT *, 
SUM(HighLevelProfit) OVER(partition by Year, 
Month ORDER BY Day, Month, Year) AS HLProfit, 
SUM(UnearnedRevenue_Total) 
OVER(partition by Year, Month ORDER BY Day, Month, Year) AS UnearnedRev
FROM TEST""")
```